# Make specific part of window invisible

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to create some sort of snipping tool like windows has.
I have a window which covers the screen with a half transparent layer. The user can define the area of the screenshot by draging the mouse (he draws a rectangle like in the windows snipping tool). My question is: How can i make the part of the Window completely transparent, so the user can see the the area of the screenshot clearly?

Here's my code so far:

```
<Window x:Class="SnippingToolPro.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Width="525" 
    Height="350" 
    AllowsTransparency="True" 
    WindowStyle="None" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    Opacity="0.5">
<Canvas>

</Canvas>
```

Any suggestions for getting the "hole" in the middle?

Comment: Usually, snipping tools create a full screen window which displays a screenshot and not the actual screen. In other words, they are not working with transparency effects. You can see this when you play a video and start the snipping tool. You will see a still frame of the video.

Comment: You're right! Good suggestion, but even if i do that, i have the same problem, right?

Comment: No, you don't. You simple display a mask on top of the screenshot. And depending on the rectangle, this mask changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        WindowStyle="None"
        Background="Transparent">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition  Width="20"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Cursor="Wait" Fill="Black" Opacity=".01" IsHitTestVisible="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The red rectangles are just to demonstrate the borders. The inner Rectangle represents the area you want to perform your selection

Comment: Seems like the best solution for me. Thanks!